# Terraform - Kubernetes - Helm Release - Generate Password

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, terraform, kubernetes-helm

**given is following scenario**

- Terraform is used to generate 2 Kubernetes Namespaces
- **Namespace A** contains RabbitMQ

  - RabbitMQ is installed via HELM-chart via terraform
  - Password-secret for RabbitMQ is generated, if not set, in HELM-chart
- **Namespace B** contains applications which access RabbitMQ

  - Therefor the password-secret needs to be copied from **A -> B** (or generated in B)

---

How do I get the secret into namespace B with **pure terraform logic**?

**My ideas:**

- simply copy secret from **A -> B** (was not able to find a solution for that)
- read the password value from secret in **A** and create a new secret in **B** (was only able to find solutions where the secret was initially generated by terraform)
- generate the password-secret with terraform "random_password"-resource and use it in the helm-chart

  - could work if I can have a conditional check if a terraform var is not set = generate, else use the var-value

Are there good solutions for that problem?

Comment: This is probably too broad as it is. Please could you rework your question so that you show what you've tried so far as a [mcve] and also the issues you've had with that approach(es)?

Comment: `random_password` should avoid regenerating the password, if there's already one known in the Terraform state file; but you'd have to push the password into both services A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform's kubernetes provider appears to have a kubernetes_secret data source:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/data-sources/secret

So theoretically at least, depending on the K8s credentials you are willing to provide to terraform while running the config, you may be able to just add a data source to the config for Namespace B:

```
data "kubernetes_secret" "rabbit_password" {
  metadata {
    name = "rabbit_password"
    namespace = "namespace_a"
  }
}
```

And then refer to the data where you need it as:

```
data.kubernetes_secret.rabbit_password.data["rabbitmq-password"]
```

Comment: I totally forgot this question. Yes that is the way how I did it!